# Why undefined method "has_many" in Rspec example?

Tags: activerecord, rspec

I am playing around with an Example on testing a has_many through association in RSpec. 
I am getting a

```
   1) Foo specifies items
       Failure/Error: subject.should have_many(:items)
       NoMethodError:
         undefined method `has_many?' for #
       # ./spec/models/foo_spec.rb:10
```

My question: Why would has_many be undefined?

The spec is:

```
describe Foo do
  it "specifies items" do
    subject.should have_many(:items)
  end
end
```

My models are:

foo.rb:

```
 class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bars
   has_many :items, :through => :bars
 end
```

bar.rb:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
  belongs_to :item
end
```

and item.rb:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :foos, :through => :bars
  has_many :bars
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there is no `has_many?` method on model objects. And `rspec-rails` does not provide such matcher by default. However, `shoulda-matchers` gem does:

```
describe Post do
  it { should belong_to(:user) }
  it { should have_many(:tags).through(:taggings) }
end

describe User do
  it { should have_many(:posts) }
end
```

(example from shoulda-matchers [documentation](http://rubydoc.info/github/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers/master/frames))

Just add `gem 'shoulda-matchers'` to your `Gemfile` and you will be able to use that syntax.